# wxpython : changing background / foreground image dynamically

Tags: wxpython

I am writing a GUI flow using wxPython which has 4 pages (or more). They way I have approached is creating 4 (or more) classes with each class defining its own static (background) and dynamic images / content. In my application I would then programmatically create instances class required and capture events on that page. Based upon the event triggered the registered handler would destroy current class and switch to other class(page). So my code actually creates X classes with each class having its own method to set background / foreground content/images:

```
def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
    dc = evt.GetDC()

    if not dc:
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
        dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
    dc.Clear()
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(self.image)
    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)

def buttonClick(self, evt):
    parent = self.frame
    self.Destroy()
    DispatchState(parent, "admin1.png", 1)
```

The issue is that the second page does not comes up at all in screen.

Below is my complete code. Note I have created 2 classes (MainPanel, SecondPanel)that creates a screen on panel in my application frame. It then waits for an event. Once I get the desired event I delete the current class and create an instance of new class:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class SecondPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent, image, state):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.state = state
    self.image = image
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)

    self.buttonOne=wx.Image("image1.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.button=wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, self.buttonOne, pos=(100,50))
    self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.buttonClick)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    def buttonClick(self, evt):
    parent = self.frame
    self.Destroy()
    DispatchState(parent, "admin0.png", 0)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
    dc = evt.GetDC()

    if not dc:
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
        dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
    dc.Clear()
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(self.image)
    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent, image, state):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.state = state
    self.image = image
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)
    self.buttonOne=wx.Image("image0.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.button=wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, self.buttonOne, pos=(100,50))
    self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.buttonClick)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    def buttonClick(self, evt):
    parent = self.frame
    self.Destroy()
    DispatchState(parent, "admin1.png", 1)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
    dc = evt.GetDC()

    if not dc:
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
        dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
    dc.Clear()
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(self.image)
    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)


 class Main(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(800, 480))
        self.state = 0
        self.image = 'admin0.png'

def DispatchState(frame, image, state):
        if state == 0 :
            print image
            print state
            MainPanel(frame, image, state)
        if state == 1 :
            print image
            print state
            SecondPanel(frame, image, state)
        frame.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    DispatchState(app.frame,app.image, app.state)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The reason I have selected this approach is that I can easily switch from one state to other such that I can switch to any screen / page. If suppose tomorrow we need to dynamically add / remove more pages - it can be easily done. I would need to create the page (class) and add its state in DispatchState() global method.

But for me currently second screen does not gets rendered at all. Also please comment on my approach - is there any better way I can achieve this - what are the things I should take care or what is erroneous in my code?

Comment: your program have problem with refreshing. If I double press button second screen doesn't show but if I change window size window is refreshed and second screen is shown. I still don't know how to fix it - `Update()`, `Refresh()`, `Layout()` doesn't work.

Comment: BTW: your code is ... strange. In my opinion `DispatchState` should be part of Frame class, and Frame should create and destroy Panel in `DispatchState` (`self.panel = MyPanel()`, `self.panel.Destroy()`) and Panel should call parent and DispatchState (`self.parent.DispatchState()`). This way it is more Object oriented.

Comment: Thanks for the design approach. I also tried various ways to solve display of second background image but unable to come to a solution.

Comment: If I add `self.Fit()` in `SecondPanel.__init__` and `MainPanel.__init__` I can see part of new screen but it is not what you expect.

Comment: I think I found some solution but it require to add Sizer to Frame so I have to create class MyFrame(wx.Frame) - I'm cleaning code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solution.

I have to create `MyFrame` class to add **sizer** which resize *Panel* to *Frame* size.

I add `DispatchState` as `ChangePanel` to `MyFrame` to make it more Object oriented. Now *Panel* call *Frame* function `ChangePanel` and *Frame* create/destroy panels.

Because `SecondPanel` and `MainPanel` are very similar I made one `MyPanel` class - to have less work with removing my errors :) - see **DRY** rule: [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself)

(*I attache my bitmaps so other users can run this code too*)

(*I use ball1.png, ball2.png in place image0.bmp, image1.bmp*)

```
import wx

#######################################################################

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, state, button_image, background_image):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        print "(debug) MyPanel.__init__: state:", state

        self.parent = parent
        self.state  = state

        self.button_image = button_image
        self.background_image = background_image


        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)

        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        #self.buttonOne=wx.Image("image1.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.buttonImage = wx.Image(button_image, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.button = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, self.buttonImage, pos=(100,50))

        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.buttonClick)

        self.backgroundImage = wx.Bitmap(self.background_image)

        vsizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(vsizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)

        self.SetSizer(hSizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    def buttonClick(self, evt):
        print "(debug) MyPanel.buttonClick"
        self.parent.ChangePanel()

    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        dc = evt.GetDC()

        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.backgroundImage, 0, 0)

#######################################################################

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, size=(800,480)):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=size)

        self.state = None
        self.panel = None

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.Show() # Show is used to show/hide window not to update content

        self.ChangePanel()

    #--------------------------

    def ChangePanel(self):

        print "(debug) MyFrame.ChangePanel: state:", self.state

        if self.state is None or self.state == 1:
            # change state
            self.state = 0 

            # destroy old panel
            if self.panel:
                self.panel.Destroy()

            # create new panel
            self.panel = MyPanel(self, self.state, "ball1.png", "admin0.png")

            # add to sizer
            self.sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        elif self.state == 0 :
            # change state
            self.state = 1 

            # destroy old panel
            if self.panel:
                self.panel.Destroy()

            # create new panel
            self.panel = MyPanel(self, self.state, "ball2.png", "admin1.png")

            # add to sizer
            self.sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        else:
            print "unkown state:", self.state

        self.Layout() # refresh window content

#######################################################################

class Application(wx.App):

    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)   
        self.frame = MyFrame((800, 480))

    def run(self):
        self.MainLoop()

#######################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

ball1.png [image: ball1.png] ball2.png [image: ball2.png]

admin0.png
[image: admin0.png]

admin1.png
[image: admin1.png]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In fact the only other way I found is having separate frames for each class in my case.